# Reload data without refreshing the page using Ajax and Twig

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twig, silex

I have a page where a user can write a comment and post it by a simple form.
I'm trying, without success, to do this with ajax using twig.
I can send the ajax request to my controller without problem and the comment is saved in my database.
My issue is to reload a part of my twig template without refreshing the whole page.

The return of my controller:

```
return $app['twig']->render('@views_suivi/suivi_affaire.html.twig', array('cache' => false,
                'auto_reload' => true,
                'affaire' => $affaire,
                'comments' => $comments
                ));
```

$comments countains all the comments of an article. When I send an ajax request, my table comment is updated. Is there a way to update the variable $comments and re-send it to my twig without refreshing the whole page?

Edit: sorry, here's the code of my controller (it just insert a comment in my db)

```
function addCommentAjax(Application $app, Request $request)
{
    $cmt = new CommentaireQueries($app);

    $postParams = $app["request"]->request->all();
    //var_dump($postParams);
    if(isset($postParams['files'])) unset($postParams['files']);
    return !empty($postParams) ? $cmt->insertCommentAffaire($app,$postParams) : false;
}
```

Ajax: 'AjoutCommentaire' is the route to my controller addCommentAjax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        url      : "AjoutCommentaire",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success  : function() {
          alert('success');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

My form:

```
<form role="form" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
     <textarea class="summernote" id="contents" rows="10" name="comment"></textarea>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="phase" value="1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="id_affaire" value="{{ affaire.id }}" />

   <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-block">Envoyer</button></center>
 </form>
```

Basically, I just want to add a comment without refreshing the page.

Thank you !

Comment: Always write complete code so the others finds the solution

Comment: Not clear at all what the specific problem is. We have no idea what your template renders or when or how you want updates to occur. Question is far too broad

Answer (score 0):

url in ajax request is not defined properly. You can't just specify route name, you should generate url by route:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "path('AjoutCommentaire', {})",
        ...
```